# How to use a custom layout as RadioButton label

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, android-custom-view

I made a custom layout that I want to implement for a `RadioButton`.
The code for the android class is here :

```
public class MyRadioButton extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener{
    private ImageView iv;
    private TextView tv;
    private RadioButton rb;

    private View view;

    public MyRadioButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.my_radio_button, this);
        setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

        rb = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        rb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    }

    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    public View getView() {
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        boolean nextState = !rb.isChecked();

        LinearLayout lGroup = (LinearLayout)view.getParent();
        if(lGroup != null){
            int child = lGroup.getChildCount();
            for(int i=0; i<child; i++){
                //uncheck all
                ((RadioButton)lGroup.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.radioButton1)).setChecked(false);
            }
        }

        rb.setChecked(nextState);
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap b){
        iv.setImageBitmap(b);
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        tv.setText(text);
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean isChecked){
        rb.setChecked(isChecked);
    }
}
```

And the code for layout is here

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/wow_visa_prepaid" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

At this moment, I can't figure out how to change the inheritance from `LinearLayout` to `RadioButton` and to keep the same layout.

This should like but with rounded corners [image: this is almost perfect]

Comment: RadioButton must has as parent RadioGroup

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: You have to use Radio Buttons in RadioGroup. Use check box instead.

Comment: I am using the radio buttons inside into a radio group but i mandatory need a custom view layout for radio button

Comment: you must to extend you class from RadioButton then

Comment: When i extend The radiobutton class The layout became unavailable

Comment: This îs îs în fact The Main issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to do the job:

**1.** When we hear about a custom view, it drives us to override `onDraw` method then drawing what we want into the view's `Canvas`.

**2.** In this case, there is a simpler approach, using `drawableLeft`. Here I've extended `AppCompatRadioButton` and set the considered layout as the `drawableLeft`.

**MyRadioButton.java**

```
package com.aminography.radiobutton;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.MultiTransformation;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.CenterCrop;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;

import jp.wasabeef.glide.transformations.MaskTransformation;

// TODO: If you are using androidx
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton;

// TODO: If you are using appcompat
//import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
//import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton;

public class MyRadioButton extends AppCompatRadioButton {

    private View view;
    private TextView textView;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public MyRadioButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyRadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyRadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

   private RequestListener<Bitmap> requestListener = new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
            redrawLayout();
            return false;
        }
    };

    public void setImageResource(int resId) {
        Glide.with(getContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(resId)
                .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(
                        new MultiTransformation<>(
                                new CenterCrop(),
                                new RoundedCornersTransformation(dp2px(getContext(), 24), 0, RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.ALL))
                        )
                )
                .listener(requestListener)
                .submit();
    }

    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Glide.with(getContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(bitmap)
                .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(
                        new MultiTransformation<>(
                                new CenterCrop(),
                                new RoundedCornersTransformation(dp2px(getContext(), 24), 0, RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.ALL))
                        )
                )
                .listener(requestListener)
                .submit();
    }

    // setText is a final method in ancestor, so we must take another name.
    public void setTextWith(int resId) {
        textView.setText(resId);
        redrawLayout();
    }

    public void setTextWith(CharSequence text) {
        textView.setText(text);
        redrawLayout();
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_radio_button_content, null);
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        redrawLayout();
    }

    private void redrawLayout() {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

        view.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap), null, null, null);
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    }

    private int dp2px(Context context, int dp) {
        return (int) (dp * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }

}
```

**my_radio_button_content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_visa" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### Visual Result:

[image]

### Note:

**1.** If you're using `appcompat` in the project, do comment the `androidx` import at the top of class and uncomment `appcompat` one.

**2.** You can change the position of the custom layout simply by changing `android:paddingLeft` for your `RadioButton`:

```
<com.aminography.radiobutton.MyRadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp" />
```

---

## *Edited:*

I've rewritten the code to address the requirement of rounded corners image using `Glide` and `Glide-Transformations`.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: is almost perfect. The radio button icon should be aligned with the textview but i think i can be done easily with top|left gravity

Comment: Yes, using `android:gravity` and `android:paddingTop` for the `RadioButton`, it's possible to align them.

Comment: I succeeded with gravity but i am having one more issue. I need that the image to have always rounded corners. `ImageView roundedImageView = containerLL.findViewById(R.id.roundedImageView);
                    roundedImageView.setClipToOutline(true);
                    Bitmap bitmap = AppUtil.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(new File(item.getImagePath()), width, height);
                    roundedImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    roundedImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);` This code not working when I use to the MyRadioButton

Comment: Please show me the `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource` code.

Comment: `Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.american);;
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
        imageView.invalidate();`

Comment: `public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(File imageFile, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);
    }`

Comment: And I need `R.drawable.rounded_corner`? I think you want to mask the image with `rounded_corner` shape. Am I right?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
<corners android:radius="24dp" />
</shape>`

Comment: Do you use `Glide` in your project? Decoding `Bitmap`s should not be done in the main thread. So, by using `Glide` your app will be executed smoother and less error-prone. I'll rewrite the code using glide soon.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Note that you should not set the width and height of the `ImageView` equal to `wrap_content`. As you can see above, you can set size in `dp` for it.

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201657/discussion-between-aurelianr-and-aminography).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following code and it works fine with no error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.example.myapplication.MyRadioButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

After changing the following code from:

```
public MyRadioButton(Context context) {
```

to the following code:

```
 public MyRadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
```

Is this the solution you need?

Comment: No is not. I need to keep the above layout from the question description  but `public class MyRadioButton extends LinearLayout` must be changed to `public class MyRadioButton extends RadioButton`

Answer (score 0):

**1.** When you are creating class, that extends LinearLayout or
    FrameLayout, **.xml** layout file (my_radio_button_content.xml),
    must start with "**merge**" instead "LinearLayout", otherwise it
    will be LinearLayot(**.xml**) in LinearLayout(**your class**).

```
<merge>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/wow_visa_prepaid" />
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

**2.** It's easy to create: `final ArrayList<MyRadioButton>`, and pass it
    to all children, if you want that brothers will change each
    others.

```
public MyRadioButton(Context context) {
   super(context);
   inflate(context, R.layout.my_radio_button, this); 
}

public void SetMyViewClickable(final ArrayList<String> brothers) {
    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (View brother:brothers) {
                ((RadioButton)brother.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1)).setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid this behavior of setting myViewClickable. I want that the click to be handled by the radioGroup automatically.

Comment: You can't, because it's custom view and radioButton smaller than your actual view. RadioGroup handle only radioButtons as child view.

Comment: Indeed, for that reason I need to extend the RadioButton class and to change only the layout from inside radio button.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, for example, you can use the following libraries

- https://github.com/AagitoEx/ImageRadioButton
- https://github.com/ceryle/RadioRealButton

Comment: the libraries are not what I need, see the above pictures.